# Question about the Definition of Borel Measure

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $G$ be a locally compact topological group. We say that a
>   functional $\mu\colon C_c(G)\to \mathbb{C}$ is a **Borel measure** if
>   for every compact subset $K$ of $G$, there exists a constant $C_K$
>   such that $|\mu(f)|\le C_k\|f\|$ whenever the support of $f$ lies in
>   $K$.

My questions are:

1. Does the above condition imply that $\mu$ is a bounded functional on $C_c(G)$?

If the answer is yes, I believe the Riesz representation theorem implies that $\mu$ is a (complex) Borel measure in the usual sense: a function that "measures the size of Borel subsets of $G$."

The reason I'm suspicious to the continuity of $\mu$ is the following question:

2. Suppose $V$ is a vector space that equals the union of proper subspaces $V_i$, that is, $V=\bigcup V_i$. If $f$ is a linear functional on $V$ that is bounded on each $V_i$ with norm $C_i$. Does it necessarily follow that $f$ is bounded on $V$?

I think the answer is no because $C_i$ can easily blow up for a family of nested $V_j$.

All comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\mu$ does not have to be bounded.  For instance, consider $G=\mathbb{R}$ and let $\mu$ be integration with respect to Lebesgue measure.  Then $\mu$ satisfies this criterion: you can just let $C_K$ be the measure of $K$.  But $\mu$ is not bounded: for any $N$, you can find $f\in C_c(\mathbb{R})$ such that $0\leq f\leq 1$ everywhere and $f=1$ on $[0,N]$, and then $\mu(f)\geq \int_0^N f=N$ but $\|f\|=1$.

(This of course also gives a counterexample to your second question, taking $V=C_c(\mathbb{R})$ and $V_i$ to be the functions supported in $[-i,i]$.)

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I had in mind. But can you elaborate on the reason for which $\mu$ as defined in my post should be called a Borel measure? (My point is that apparently this is not equivalent to the standard definition of the Borel measure.)

Comment: When restricted to each compact set $K$, $\mu$ does give a measure $\mu_K$ on $K$ by the Riesz representation theorem.  If every $\mu_K$ were positive, then they would glue together to give a positive (but possibly infinite) measure on all of $G$.  In general, you can decompose $\mu_K$ into real and imaginary parts and then decompose each of those into positive and negative parts, and each of the four parts will glue together to a positive measure on $G$.  So $\mu$ corresponds to an "infinite $\mathbb{C}$-valued measure", except that this is not defined in general as an ordinary measure.

Comment: (For instance, because if you have a set $A$ such that the positive part of its measure and the negative part of its measure are both infinite, there's no good way to define the measure of $A$.)